# Stream media over Internet

Tags: remote, ubuntu-server, wan, dlna

I have a server on a remote location on which are running a couple of VMs with Ubuntu Server.  I'd like to install a kind of media stream service (like DLNA),  but which I can access over the Internet (DLNA only works for LANs), so I can access it at home. As DLNA doesn't allow WAN connections I need a different protocol,  which can run on Ubuntu Server and is possibly accessible for a TV or receiver (so plex wouldn't work in this case).  Has anyone any experience with these protocols? If so, what protocol should I use?